# Customized nologin message (nologin.txt) in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to display a customized message for "/usr/sbin/nologin".
As far as I remember this can be accomplished by creating the file "/etc/nologin.txt" with the desired text in it.

But it doesn't work in Ubuntu 12.04 (LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-38-generic x86_64)) - it displays only the "standard" message:

```
$ cat /etc/nologin.txt
Sorry, there is no login shell
$ nologin
This account is currently not available.
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the output of

```
 strace /usr/sbin/nologin 2>&1 | grep open
```

These files are accessed by `nologin`. I don't have Ubuntu, but in Debain there's the following output:

```
 open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
 open("/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY)        = 3
 open("/var/run/utmp", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
 open("/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY)        = 3
```

Compared with a system, where `/etc/nologin.txt` is displayed (openSuSE 11), the important line is missing

```
 open("/etc/nologin.txt", O_RDONLY)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Additionally,

```
strings /usr/sbin/nologin
```

Shows that the message appears to be embedded in the binary. It's also visible with:

```
cat /usr/bin/nologin | xxd
```

It looks like the changing of the default message is not provided.

`man 5 nologin` states

> If the  file  /etc/nologin exists, login(1) will allow access only to
>   root.  Other users will be shown the contents of this file and their
>          logins will be refused.

But that's probably not, what you want either...

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing things up. Seems that Debian / Ubuntu are not accessing the nologin.txt whereas Feodora, Suse does.